# Testing `CharField(unique=True)` in django with py.test

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I'm working to move all tests for a django application over to py.test.

One case I have not been able to overcome is testing that uniqueness constraints on model fields are enforced.

An example test:

```
# requirements.txt
pytest
pytest-django
...


# myapp/models.py
from django.db import models

class UniqueModel(models.Model):
    unique_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


# myapp/tests/test_unique_model.py
from django.db import IntegrityError
import pytest
from myapp.models import UniqueModel

def test_unique(self, db):
    unique_1 = UnqiueModel(unique_field='not-unique')
    unique_1.save()
    unique_2 = UniqueModel(unique_field='not-unique')

    with pytest.raises(IntegrityError):
       unique_2.save()
```

This test fails:

```
...
        with pytest.raises(IntegrityError):
>           unique_2.save()
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'django.db.utils.IntegrityError'>
...
```

Any guidance?

Thanks!

Comment: Did it raise an error at all?  Was the `.save()` successful?

Comment: You haven't saved `unique_2`, that's why no `IntegrityError` raised.

Comment: @StephenRauch no error at all, save is successful and both objects are available with different primary keys but the same value for `unique_field` - in obvious violation of the unique constraint

Comment: @dvnguyen `unique_2` is saved on the last line of the first code block in the post. It is also saved when the code is executed, see comment above.

Comment: @Jay, so that is not a test problem. Django actualy failed.  The test caught it. DB Driver is where I would start looking.

Comment: The test passes in a clean django project with the sqlite db backend, so there's something you're not telling us. The test might be actually uncovering some issue with your db setup.

Comment: @StephenRauch this isn't an issue when using django's built-in `SimpleTestCase` - my hypothesis is that the uniqueness index in the DB is not being updated (or being simulated since the transactions aren't being executed) - thanks, will keep digging.

Comment: @hoefling running with connection to PostgreSQL via psycopg2.

Comment: So I would recommend clarifying your question to be about getting enough of Django running under pytest, because Django test runner normally does this for you.  Good Luck.

Comment: Please show the actual test that is failing. Your current code has at least a couple of issues (`self` argument even though it’s a function, misspelled Unqiue).